# Called a function of an entity in twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm looking to retrieve information from an entity by twig by passing the id as a parameter. But I block on the function in my entity:

My entity (function need call):

```
public function getNameFournisseur($id)
{
    ???
}
```

My twig:

```
{{ staticFournisseur.getNameFournisseur(idFournisseur) }}
```

My controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/new", name="new_invoice", methods={"GET","POST"})
 */
public function new(Request $request, SessionInterface $session, ArticlesRepository $articlesRepository, FournisseursRepository $fournisseursRepository): Response
{
    $invoice = new Invoice();
    $form = $this->createForm(InvoiceType::class, $invoice);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $articles = $session->get('articleInvoice', []);

    $articleData = [];

    foreach ($articles as $k => $article) {
        $articleData [] = [
            'articleInvoice' => $articlesRepository->find($k),
            'quantityInvoice' => $article
        ];
    }

    $total = 0;

    foreach ($articleData as $totalArticle) {
        $totalArticles = $totalArticle['articleInvoice']->getPrice() * $totalArticle['quantityInvoice'];
        $total += $totalArticles;
    }

    $session->set('totalHt', $total);

    $totalAllArticles = $session->get('totalHt');
    $tauxDiscount = $session->get('discountTaux');

    if (!$tauxDiscount) {
        $totalWithDiscount = $total;
    } else {
        $totalWithDiscount = $totalAllArticles - ($totalAllArticles * $tauxDiscount) / 100;
    }

    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        //$session->remove('idFournisseur');

        $id_fournisseur = (int)$request->request->get('order')['fournisseur_id'];
        $fournisseur = $fournisseursRepository->findOneBy(['id' => $id_fournisseur]);

        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($invoice);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('invoices');
    }

    return $this->render('admin/invoices/new.html.twig', [
        'staticFournisseur' => new Fournisseur(),
        'idFournisseur' => $session->get('idFournisseur'),
        'discountTaux' => $tauxDiscount,
        'totalHt' => $totalWithDiscount,
        'art' => $articleData,
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

I therefore seek to recover the name of the supplier thanks to the id that I pass as a parameter in my twig.

Comment: Have you tested it? Like just returning a dummy string from the getter for now? Does it gives you an error? If yes, what? As it stands, your question is explaining what you expect, what you did but not where you are blocked exactly (see [ask])

Comment: If I add a dd ($ id) I recover an id well but how to recover the object with the information thanks to this ID. I have to complete my function but I don't see how.

Comment: General idea — which is behind the scene, in the answer bellow — don't do that. Twig and in a larger meaning, a view is not meant for that, your controller is. In a view you should do representation of data loaded from the model in the controller, and only that. What you seek to do is a breach of the [MVC pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Answer (score 1):

`getNameFournisseur($id)` is a function that retrieves data from the database, not from a single (already loaded) entity; in other words, it should be in FournisseursRepository instead

Also, if you're using Doctrine, you usually want to load the full entity instead of just a field

```
'staticFournisseur' => $fournisseursRepository->findOneById($session->get('idFournisseur'));
```

and in twig:

```
{{ staticFournisseur.getName() }}
```

or even

```
{{ staticFournisseur.name }}
```